# get back nan values after storing in HDFStore

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, nan, hdfstore

I am storing a big dataset with lot of `NaN` values in a `HDFStore` using the following code with `python`/`pandas`:

```
with get_store(work_path+'/stores/store.h5') as store:
        for chunk in reader:
            for column in column_list:
                store.append('%s' % column, chunk[column],
                             data_columns=column)
```

And then I want to load the first column as a `numpy` array, so I have:

```
array = store.select(column_list[0]).as_matrix()
```

The problem is that I get a tiny array without any of the initial `NaN` values, because when I store the data in the store, it kinda "forget" the `NaN` values and only keep the non `NaN` values and their indexes. How can I get back the array with the initial `NaN` values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass `dropna=False`, see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.HDFStore.append.html?highlight=hdfstore.append#pandas.HDFStore.append)

FYI, you are creating a column store essentially (which may or may not fit your problem better).